# code for Location using Javascript not working -- call not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags

using the following code which does not seem to be working in my Liferay page which I have created
  
    document.write("Welcome to our visitors from "+geoplugin_city()+", "+geoplugin_countryName());

Want to use this to populate my dropdown

I want the city to be returned. IF I run this as a html file it gives the city but unable to integrate it with the liferay community version deployment which I have done

Comment: Not working, not working, not working ... yep, this question is not working ... Please explain in details what you want your code to do and what it does instead, and add the relevant code to your post too. As it is, the question is not answerable.

Comment: Show your CODE!